# TinyMCE transforms alpha lists into numbered lists on copy/paste, with the "paste" plugin

Tags: html, tinymce, html-lists, paste

I'm using TinyMCE 5.4.

### Goal

My goal is to be able to copy/paste lists like these (upper-alpha for instance) into TinyMCE:

```
A. Item 1
B. Item 2
```

**- If I remove the "[paste](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/)" plugin, it works**:

[image]

- If I add the "paste" plugin though, it breaks, and transforms the list into a numbered one:

[image]

---

### CodePen

- CodePen to demonstrate the issue: https://codepen.io/niuage/pen/MWyVEpo
- Example of a list you can use to copy paste into the tinymce editor: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mi93gyNwNnEKURw-pPtoN15OQJPI5ZqgjRW12uPl8zo/edit?usp=sharing

---

### What I tried

```
tinyMCE.init
    selector: '.wysiwyg'

    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "media table contextmenu paste"
    ]

    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media | code"

    extended_valid_elements: "iframe[height|width|style|src|title],ol[type|class|style|list-style-type],li[list-style-type]" # tried to allow the relevant attributes for ol and li.

    # paste plugin
    paste_enable_default_filters: false # tried with true and false
    paste_convert_word_fake_lists: false # tried with true and false.
    paste_retain_style_properties: "all"
```

I can't find another option that would be relevant.

Comment: have you a live version?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I added a codepen: https://codepen.io/niuage/pen/MWyVEpo. I also added a google doc file where you can find an example of a list to copy/paste into the editor provided in this codepen.

You can see that if you add the "paste" plugin, the list wont be pasted properly. Thanks.